# Layouts Throwing "Attempt to assign property of non-object" In Laravel 4

Tags: php, layout, laravel, laravel-blade

In the Layouts folder, I have a layout called signup.blade.php

In my controller, I'm assigning a layout to it like so:

```
    protected $layout = 'layouts.signup';
```

In a separate folder, named "signup" I have a file called "signup1.blade.php" It contains your typical blade template stuff. It's a section called "content". Before the code I have

```
@section('content')
```

and it's got @stop at the end.

My controller looks like this:

```
public function SignUp()
{       
    $this->layout->content = View::make('signup.signup1');
}
```

The frustrating part is that this is working with another layout and controller. I've double checked they're the same, and this one does not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Cn you show the error message?

Comment: http://imgur.com/wZIr4WW

Answer (score 4):

So, assuming this controller extends BaseController (it must for $layout to work), the [code execution sets](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php#L14) `$this->layout` to `View::make($this->layout)`.

Your error seems to show that `$this->layout` is not getting set to a View object correctly.

Try to run this and see if `$this->layout` is an object/class, and if so, what class it is.

```
public function SignUp()
{       
    echo gettype($this->layout);
    echo get_class($this->layout);
}
```

Knowing what `$this->layout` does not get changed into a `View` object means that the  [setupLayout()](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php#L10) method is either not called or, more likely, not the result of `View::make($this->layout)` is not a proper view (perhaps it's silently failing for some reason).

The above steps hopefully give you a clue into whats happening there. Perhaps `layouts.signup`  isn't a layout the app is finding?

What do your routes look like?

Comment: Ok, figured out a cause. If your class name is the same as your layout name you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
class UsersController extends Controller
```

to

```
class UsersController extends BaseController
```

Hopefully the author of Confide fixes this :-)